# No icon for unsorted columns in angular ui-grid

Tags: css, angular-ui-grid, angularjs-1.5

I am using angular ui-grid with angular 1.5.

Currently, when a column is not sorted, it does not show an icon. But I require an icon to be displayed indicating that the column can be sorted. Such as this - [fa-sort](http://fontawesome.io/icon/sort/)

The css has a class -

```
.ui-grid-icon-blank::before { 
    width: 1em; 
    content: '\c358'; 
}
```

but on changing the content of the icon, the icon does not appear due to another class `ui-grid-invisible` applied on it. On removal of that class the priorities are visible as well, which is not required.

Basically, looking for a solution to this [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/2274#issuecomment-235820691)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time you might have an answer for this question but worth sharing how I fixed it.

[fa-sort](http://fontawesome.io/icon/sort/) - is a Font Awesome icon. So I fixed it by adding bellow classes.

```css
.ui-grid-invisible {
     visibility: visible;
}

.ui-grid-icon-blank::before {
    content: "\f0dc";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```